# Implement a scrollable drawer with flutter, it shows a bottom overflow when I rotate

Tags: flutter, navigation-drawer, flutter-layout, drawer

Bottom overflow in `Drawer` when I rotate the screen.

Comment: Please add some code which you have tried or any reference image

Answer (score 8):

Use `SingleChildScrollView` like this

```
drawer: Drawer(
child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
                  YourWidgetsHere(),
                  YourWidgetsHere(),
                  YourWidgetsHere(),
                  YourWidgetsHere(),
                  YourWidgetsHere(),
                  YourWidgetsHere(),
                  YourWidgetsHere(),
                  YourWidgetsHere(),
        ]),),)
```

Or

```
Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[           
ListTile(
              dense: true,
              title: Text("Example"),
              leading: new Image.asset(
                "assets/images/example.png",
                width: 20.0,
              ),
            ),
]),),
```

Comment: What's the benefit of copying other 2 answers and putting it as yours? -1 from me.

Comment: What??!! Really look at the code and see it's different, okay?

Comment: Just by adding one or two properties doesn't make your code look unique, everyone can do that, the main point of question was to either use `ListView` or `SingleChildScrollView`, may I know what special value you added to the post?

Answer (score 3):

Put it inside a `SingleChildScrollView`

Answer (score 2):

Use `ListView` for your `Drawer`.

```
drawer: Drawer(
  child: ListView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    children: <Widget>[
      YourWidgetsHere(),
      YourWidgetsHere(),
      YourWidgetsHere(),
      YourWidgetsHere(),
      YourWidgetsHere(),
      YourWidgetsHere(),
      YourWidgetsHere(),
      YourWidgetsHere(),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **Wrap** instead of **ListView** or **Column**