# How to make the List scrollable in the drawer

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, scroll, multiple-columns

I want to make the inner column scrollable. how can i acheive it,tried replacing with list view,and Single child scroll view but not working
This is the widget structure

```
  >Drawer
  >>Container
    >>>SingleChildScrollView(never Scrollable)
       >>>>Column
          >>>>>Drawer Header
          >>>>>Column
          >>>>>ListView.builder(never scrollble physics)
          >>>>>Row
```

[image]

Please Help

Comment: does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57869679/implement-a-scrollable-drawer-with-flutter-it-shows-a-bottom-overflow-when-i-ro

Comment: not working....

Comment: can you please share code you had tried so far

Comment: added the image

Answer (score 1):

You need something to limit the height of the `ListView` when it is used inside scrollable. The easiest way is to set `shrinkWrap` property of `ListView` to true.

see [Vertical viewport was given unbounded height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50252569/vertical-viewport-was-given-unbounded-height)

Comment: not working .."RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Column"

Comment: I forgot about the `SingleChildScrollView` in my previous answer, it should be working now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one once and let us know.

Here the SingleChildScrollView widget is used to wrap the inner Column widget, allowing it to be scrollable.

```
   Scaffold(
  drawer: Drawer(
    child: Container(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            DrawerHeader(),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  // your scrollable content
                ],
              ),
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                // return a widget for each item in your list
              },
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                // other content
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  // other properties of the Scaffold widget
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a List<Map<String, dynamic>> in which your content and their action will be stored i.e.

```
final _actions = [
    {'name': 'My Profile', 'onTap': () {}},
    {'name': 'Setting', 'onTap': () {}},
    {'name': 'Terms and Conditions', 'onTap': () {}},
    {'name': 'Privacy Policy', 'onTap': () {}},
  ];
```

Then you can implement your drawer

```
drawer: Drawer(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      const UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
        accountName: Text('accountName'),
        accountEmail: Text('accountEmail'),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (_, i) {
            final action = _actions[i];
            return ListTile(
              onTap: (action['onTap'] as VoidCallback),
              title: Text((action['name'] as String?) ?? ''),
            );
          },
          itemCount: _actions.length,
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```